# Cart items - number and value

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, mini-cart

There's a big difference when using:

```
$_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount();
```

and

```
$_cartQty = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

Results are totally different (12 vs 4).

The same when inspecting the elements using:

```
$_items = $this->getRecentItems();
```

or

```
$_items = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItems();
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Minicart or sidebar cart does not show all the items added to cart, where as it shows the last few recent items there.

So basically `$this->getSummaryCount();` or `$this->getRecentItems();` in particular `phtml` gives you the items to show in sidebar.

Where as cart gives you all items.

You can define the max number through system config. Go to, **System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart Sidebar > Maximum Display Recently Added Item(s)**